# Feynman's $i\epsilon$ prescription in path integrals (Mark Srednicki)

Tags: path-integral, wick-rotation

On page 63 in M.S. book , why m^(-1) goes to (1-iε)m^(-1) or m -> (1+iε)m 
and how can i verify eq.(7.3)?

On page 63 writes :
Looking at $H(P,Q)= \frac{1}{2m}  P^2 +\frac{1}{2}mω^2Q^2$ 
we see that multiplying H by 1-iε is equivalent to the replacements

$m^-1->(1-iε)m^-1$
[or equivalently ,m->(1+iε)m] and $mω^2->(1-iε)mω^2$

Why these replacements ?
Then from equation 
$$\int DpDq \exp i\int (p\frac{dq}{dt}-(1-iε)H+fg)dt $$ goes to eq

$$\int Dq \exp i\int [\frac{1}{2}(1+iε)m(\frac{dq}{dt})^2-\frac{1}{2}(1-iε)mω^2q^2+fg]dt $$ equation(7.3)

Comment: Hi Chris7, welcome to Physics SE. This website generally encourages questions useful to the broader public, so it might be a good idea to include the formula and at least a bit of context or motivation for the calculation you are talking about.

Comment: Υou're right, I'm sorry.